# css let element width auto grow while parent width auto

Tags: html, css

I have a html structure like this and some basic style

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  /* this is must */
  height: auto;
  /* this is must */
  max-width: 300px;
}

.container .row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container .row .left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.container .row .right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The style may not working, I only pasted the basic part of it.
What I want to achieve is, the parent element has a max-width, it contains  multiple rows, each row has two elements, 'left' and 'right'. I give a fixed width to 'left' element, and a min-width/max-width to 'right' element. I would like the width of the right element auto grow as the content grow until the max-width, but if the content is short, the right element shall also shrink.
I tried table and flex box, but no luck. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have to specify the max-width to the .right class.

1) The overall container's max-width:300px and left one's width: is 100px, so the remaining 200px; you can give it to right row.

2) Have added background for better understanding.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<style>
    .container {
        display: block;
        width: auto; /* this is must */
        height: auto; /* this is must */
        max-width: 300px;
    }
    .container .row{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background-color:Red;
    }
    .container .row .left{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
    .container .row .right{
        display: inline-block;
        height: auto;
         background-color:green;
         max-width: 200px;
         overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left">qweqweqwe</div>
        <div class="right">qweqweqwew<p>afdllssssssssdddddddddssssssssss</p><p>asdasdasdadsas</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left">qweqweqwe</div>
        <div class="right">qweqweqwe</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left">qweqweqw</div>
        <div class="right">qweqweqweqwe</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the [codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/ZJKOdv) sample here and check it with your requirement. Also, let me know if there is something that you want to get from.

```
    .container .row{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .container .row .left{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
    }
    .container .row .right{
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 150px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` to your `.row` class and set `min-width: 100px` to `.right` - see a working jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o3o9j4za/1/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">1234</div>
    <div class="right">4312</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">1235</div>
    <div class="right">qweqwereqwr</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">5342</div>
    <div class="right">3g43g3g3g</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    display: block;
    width: auto; /* this is must */
    height: auto; /* this is must */
    max-width: 300px;
}
.container .row{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:flex;
}
.container .row .left{
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:#ff0;
}
.container .row .right{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    background-color:#f0f;
}
```

Note, that your flex container (.row) is affected by the max-width of .container.

(Edit: misread a bit - should be like you want it now?)

Answer (score 0):

How about this flexbox solution? I think it comes closest to what you are looking for:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">test left</div>
    <div class="right">test right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">test left</div>
    <div class="right">test right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">test left</div>
    <div class="right">test right</div>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.left {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
}

.right {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  width: 180px;
}
```

And the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xr7ebmsz/

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can try this one for your class "right"

```
.right{
     width:calc(100% - 100px);
 }
```